# Подключение модулей (extensions) php во FreeBSD 10.1

Tags: php, freebsd

Есть машина с FreeBSD 10.1, сеть настроена, порты обновлены. Пытаюсь запустить сборку Apache 2.2 + MySQL + php5.5(+extensions) + phpMyAdmin. Apache запустился, страницу "It works!" отобразил. PHP тоже установился, для апача ставил модуль php55_mod. Получилось вывести `phpinfo()`. И вот на следуещем шаге у меня затык: не устанавливается phpMyAdmin:

`Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in /usr/local/www/phpMyAdmin/libraries/php-gettext/gettext.inc on line 177`

После некоторого гугления понял, что дело в том, что у меня не установились модуль mbstring и еще до кучи. В логах однотипные ошибки:

```
Unknown(0) : Warning - PHP Startup: mbstring: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20121212,NTS
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20121212,NTS,debug
These options need to match
```

Я понимаю, что у меня debug-php скомпилирован, хотя я явно не указывал Debug при конфигурировании. Или может я не так понимаю? Вообще суть вопроса проста: как мне добиться идентичности строк? 
Либо так:

```
Module compiled with build ID=API20121212,NTS,debug
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20121212,NTS,debug
```

Либо так:

```
Module compiled with build ID=API20121212,NTS
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20121212,NTS
```

Буду весьма благодарен за ответ.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я взял виртуальную машину (qemu-kvm), поставил туда FreeBSD 10.1-RELEASE amd64 и попробовал воспроизвести Вашу проблему. Мои шаги:

```
# pkg bootstrap && pkg install perl5 python curl
```

Сэкономим немного времени, поставив некоторые зависимости руками, из пакетов, без сборки из исходников. Теперь займёмся портами:

```
# portsnap fetch extract && portsnap fetch update
# cd /usr/ports/lang/php55 && make config-recursive
```

Галка "DEBUG" в конфиге порта lang/php55 по умолчанию снята, может у Вас в ней дело? Оставляю всё, как есть, жму OK.

```
# cd /usr/ports/lang/php55-extensions && make config
```

В диалоге конфигурации порта lang/php55-extensions отмечаю в дополнение к отмеченному из коробки галки BCMATH, CURL, FTP, GD, GETTEXT, MBSTRING, MCRYPT, MYSQLI, OPENSSL, PDO_MYSQL, READLINE, SOCKETS, XMLRPC, ZIP. У остальных портов принимаю дефолтную конфигурацию. Теперь можно собирать PHP (ставим порт php55-extensions, порт php55 поставится как зависимость):

```
# make config-recursive && make install clean
```

PHP с модулями установлен. Ставим MySQL:

```
# cd /usr/ports/databases/mysql55-server && make install clean
# echo 'mysql_enable=YES' >> /etc/rc.conf && /usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysql-server start
```

Готово. Ставим Apache:

```
# cd /usr/ports/www/mod_php55 && make config-recursive && make install clean
# echo 'ServerName mytest.freebsd' >> /usr/local/etc/apache24/httpd.conf
# echo 'AddType application/x-httpd-php .php' >> /usr/local/etc/apache24/httpd.conf
# echo 'apache24_enable=YES' >> /etc/rc.conf && /usr/local/etc/rc.d/apache24 start
```

Apache запущен, "It Works" показывает, `phpinfo()` показывает все нужные модули. Поставим phpmyadmin:

```
# cd /usr/ports/databases/phpmyadmin && make install clean
# mv -- /usr/local/www/phpMyAdmin /usr/local/www/apache24/data/
# mkdir -p /usr/local/www/apache24/data/phpMyAdmin/config && chown -R www:www /usr/local/www/apache24/data/phpMyAdmin
```

`phpmyadmin` установлен, настроем его, зайдя на `http://our-test-host/phpMyAdmin/setup/index.php`, по окончании настройки получим файл `config.inc.php`, который надо подложить в корень pma:

```
# mv /usr/local/www/apache24/data/phpMyAdmin/config/config.inc.php /usr/local/www/apache24/data/phpMyAdmin/
```

Всё, можно логиниться в phpmyadmin и ломать MySQL. *(на самом деле нет, так как из коробки у MySQL пользователь root логинится без пароля, а pma этому сопротивляется - надо или задать руту пароль, или добавить `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = 1;` в конфиг pma.)*

Не воспроизвелась у меня Ваша проблема. Где-то Вы что-то напутали, или мы изначально говорили о разных вещах - тогда мой эксперимент это должен показать.

**Update:** забыл про таймзоны:

```
# cd /usr/ports/misc/pecl-timezonedb && make install clean
```

и после этого перезапустить апач - PHP подхватит новую timezonedb, в чём можно убедиться в `phpinfo()`:

```
Olson Timezone Database Version     2015.4
Timezone Database   external
```

Comment: Хорошо, если переустановить php5.5 и все расширения?

Comment: Изменил системную дату на текущую, удалил все расширения и пхп. Поставил заново, версия пыха теперь 5.5.24, все модули встали норм, а вот `phpinfo()` выдает мне 5.5.14...Перезапускал и апач, и систему. Не помогло.

Comment: Так, модуль для апача же тоже надо переустановить... Невнимателен.

Comment: Вы решили проблему?

Comment: Получилось в итоге запустить phpmyadmin, завтра буду разбираться с остальными проблемами. Возможно завтра появятся новые вопросы =D Я очень Вам благодарен!

Comment: Не за что =) Новые вопросы задавайте отдельно, я мониторю тег [[tag:freebsd]]

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо пересобрать порт lang/php5-extensions, сделав `make config` и в открывшемся окошке выбрать нужные модули. То есть последовательность Ваших действий примерно такова (пишу по памяти, с путями могу путать):

```
$ su
# cd /usr/ports/lang/php5-extensions
# make config

(откроется псевдографическое окно конфигурации,
в котором нужно "довыбрать" нужные вам модули php)

# make deinstall reinstall clean
```

Добавлено: список собранных модулей php можно консольно посмотреть командой `php -m`

Comment: AntonioK, нужные мне модули уже были выбраны. Все так и делал. И не раз. Проблема в том, что расширения не ориентированы на версию php debug. ID API совпадают. Мне нужен именно php5.5, так как хочу поработать с yii2.

Comment: в выводе `php -m` нужные модули видны?

Comment: Да. А при выводе phpinfo() ничего + логи говорят об ошибках.

Comment: сравните путь к бинарнику `php` в выводе `phpinfo()` и путь, который покажет консольная команда `which php` - совпадают ли?

Comment: Простите, но задам глупый вопрос: где `phpinfo()` показывает путь до бинарника? До конфигурационных файлов только вижу. `which php` -/usr/local/bin/php. Одно точно скажу, пути /usr/local/bin/php там точно нигде нет. И вот еще: PATH /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/home/mikhail/bin

Comment: хм, действительно, путь до бинарника там не светится, прошу прощения. а путь до конфигов - `/usr/local/etc`? что говорит `whereis php`? я пытаюсь понять, тот ли php использует apache, который Вы наблюдаете при запуске `php -m`. возможно, у Вас в системе получилось два "независимых" php по разным путям, один с нужными модулями, другой - без.

Comment: дурацкий вопрос, но Вы apache перезапускали после манипуляций с php?

Comment: `whereis php`: php: /usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/man/man1/php.1.gz /usr/ports/archivers/php55-phar/work/stage/usr/local/etc/php. 
Перезапускал. Вполне может быть , что я намудрил с установками-переустановками php. Еще такой интересный момент: в секции авторов модулей указаны те модули, что выводятся  `php -m `. Второй день уже бьюсь с этой проблемой. Пытался переустановить php, чтобы был non-debug

Comment: Вы php и модули только из портов ставили? Ничего не собирали из исходников, не ставили pecl-ы? Можете выгрепать все установленные порты с вхождением строки 'php|pecl'?

Comment: Да, ставил только из портов. У меня даже не стоит pecl.

Comment: У меня кончились предположения. Попробую воспроизвести Ваше окружение в виртуалке и проверить руками. Интригует меня Ваша проблема.

Comment: А без `pecl` Вы не сможете обновлять таймзоны для PHP - они у него свои, системные он не считывает. Так что с `pecl` надо будет тоже разобраться.